# How to execute functions synchronously to get the right output

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, synchronous

I am making an application which reads a file and extracts the data line by line. Each line is then stored as an array element and that array is required as the final output.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

var output_array=[];
const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(inp_file),
    console: false
});
readInterface.on('line', function(line) {
    //code for pushing lines into output_array after doing conditional formatting
}

callback (null, output_array);
```

With this I am getting an empty array.
Though if I use 'setTimeout' then it's working fine

```
setTimeout(() => {
  callback (null, output_array);
}, 2000);
```

How can I execute this synchronously without having to use 'setTimeout'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your callback from [readline's close event](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) handler. That way your callback will happen after all lines are read.

```
readInterface.on('close', function(line) {
  callback (null, output_array);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute asynchronous functions synchronously. But `readline` supports the `close` event, which is triggered when the inputfile is completely read, so you can call the callback there.

```
readInterface.on('close', () => {
   callback(null, output_array);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you could output the content on the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) event, but you could also use a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like this:

```
function readFile(fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(fileName).on('error', error => {
          // Failed to create stream so reject.
          reject(error);
        }),
      });
      const output = [];
      readInterface.on('error', error => {
        // Some error occurred on stream so reject.
        reject(error);
      });
      readInterface.on('line', line => {
        output.push(line);
      });
      readInterface.on('close', () => {
        // Resolve the promise with the output.
        resolve(output);
      });
  });
}

readFile(inp_file)
  .then(response => {
    callback(null, response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Take care of any errors.
  });
```

I removed the `console` setting when calling `createInterface()` since it does not seem to be a valid [`option`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options).